# Cytoscape - ¿Es posible establecer varias columnas como origen y y varias como objetivo tras importar una red desde un archivo?

Tags: nodos, red

En Cytoscape 3.9.1:
Importamos como red, no como tabla no asignada, una tabla Excel con varias columnas. Por ejemplo:
Origen A | Destino B | Origen B | Destino C | Origen C | Destino D

Una tabla así tiene varias peculiaridades en cuanto a sus nodos:
1- Necesitamos calificar como origen varias columnas (Origen A, Origen B, Origen C).
2- También necesitamos calificar como destino varias columnas (Destino B, Destino C, Destino D).
3- El contenido de Origen X (X=B,C) es igual al contenido de Destino X (X=B,C).
Los atributos de cada nodo son, de momento, irrelevantes.

¿Hay alguna forma de utilizar distintas columnas como origen y otras como destino?
Cuando lo intento, usando Mayúsculas, Control o Alt, también con sus combinaciones, el segundo,por ejemplo destino C, elimina el primero, por ejemplo Destino B.
Pasa igual con los orígenes, con lo que sólo puedo tener una columna origen y una destino.

En mi opinión una tabla construida de esta forma debería generar un conjunto de redes separadas en la que una o dos representasen los núcleos de las rutas A -> B -> C -> D, mientras que aparecerían
redes menores aisladas.
Esto se produciría porque la red principal puede ser A -> B -> C mientras que habría rutas que estarían aisladas de esos tres nodos. Por ejemplo una ruta E -> B estaría aislada porque en la tabla no existe el conjunto Origen E -> Destino B. Sin embargo, y eso es lo que importa, sí existe esa ruta.

La construcción de la tabla es ad hoc. Su objetivo es romper la red en subredes y poder determinar la red más relevante, entendiendo como tal aquella con más nodos unidos de forma directa por rutas. Eso debería permitir, estudiando las redes menores, reconstruir el conjunto completo de rutas entre dos nodos cualesquiera.

En determinados problemas esa red es la esencial, mientras que las otras resultan secundarias o irrelevantes.

Comment: Hola Lorenzo, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema).

Comment: Gracias Marce. pero no es un problema de código. Es un problema de utilización de Cytoscape cuando intento crear una red a partir de una hoja Excel como la descrita. El problema es poder seleccionar varias columnas como nodo de origen y varias como nodo de destino. El hecho de que, salvo la primera (origen) y la última (destino), todas las columnas están duplicadas, como origen y como destino no afecta al problema ya que tienen nombres distintos y no existen auto-enlaces en los que nodo de origen sea igual a nodo de destino.